# Return multiple image file from spring boot api

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have created an method which can return multiple image data but the problem is that I want the respone to be a proper image but htis methos return the image byte data in json format.

```
 public List<ResponseEntity<byte[]>> viewImage(@PathVariable("id") Long id) throws NoSuchElementException, NotFoundException {
        List<byte[]> bytes = productService.showImage(id);
        List<ResponseEntity<byte[]>> responseEntities = new ArrayList<>();

        for (byte[] imageBytes : bytes) {
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);

            ResponseEntity<byte[]> responseEntity = ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .headers(headers)
                    .body(imageBytes);

            responseEntities.add(responseEntity);
        }

        return responseEntities;
    }
```

the response of this looks like
[postman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52Bau.png)

I also tryed

```
public ResponseEntity<List<ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>>> viewImages() {
        List<byte[]> imageBytesList = getImageBytesList();

        if (imageBytesList.isEmpty()) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }

        List<ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>> responseEntities = new ArrayList<>();

        for (byte[] imageBytes : imageBytesList) {
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
            headers.setContentLength(imageBytes.length);

            InputStreamResource inputStreamResource = new InputStreamResource(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes));
            ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> responseEntity = ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .headers(headers)
                    .body(inputStreamResource);

            responseEntities.add(responseEntity);
        }

        HttpHeaders multipartHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        multipartHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_MIXED);

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .headers(multipartHeaders)
                .body(responseEntities);
    }
```

but it is giving error
[org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class java.util.ArrayList] with preset Content-Type 'multipart/mixed'] now what to do

Comment: What do you mean by "a proper image" ?

Comment: I mean that I need images as response not the image byte data

Comment: Okay, have you tried using the  `produces` parameter like in [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-return-image-file) ?

Comment: How do you expect your response to be an image, while you actually return multiple images in one go, so not a image proper file?